# Breaking down a set into smaller sets

Tags: java, android, kotlin, set

I have a set of over 40,000 items and I want to break it down into multiple sets of 5,000 items each because Room won't let me use a set of 5,041 items at once as an argument.

How do I do it?

```
fun breakDownSet(set: Set<String>) : List<Set<String>> {
    val sets = ArrayList<Set<String>>()
    // TODO

    return sets
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`chunked`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html).

```kotlin
fun breakDownSet(set: Set<String>): List<Set<String>> = set.chunked(5000) { it.toSet() }
```

This will split your set in several sets not containing more than 5000 items each.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, don't know Kotlin, so here is Java version. Should be easy for you to convert to Kotlin.

```java
static List<Set<String>> breakDownSet(Set<String> set, int size) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
    List<Set<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += size)
        result.add(new HashSet<>(list.subList(i, Math.min(i + size, list.size()))));
    return result;
}
```